# react native firebase subcollection

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to have a subcollection with the order products. The cart has two products, but I am getting the subcollection with only one product. I tried the same logic in an expo application and it works good, but in react native it is not working properly.

This is my code

```
const user = useSelector(state => state.userLogged.data);
const loggedUser = useSelector(state => state.authUser.authenticated);
const cartProducts = useSelector(state => state.cart);
console.log(typeof cartProducts);
const placeOrder = async () => {
    let orderId;
    let doc = await firestore()
        .collection('Orders')
        .add({
            totalPrice: route?.params?.orderPrice,
            userId: loggedUser,
            createdAt: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        })
     const orderId = doc.id;
    for (const key in cartProducts) {
        doc = await firestore()
            .collection('Orders')
            .doc(orderId)
            .collection('Products')
            .add({
                productTitle: cartProducts[key].title,
                productImage: cartProducts[key].image[0],
                productQuantity: cartProducts[key].quantity,
                productPrice: cartProducts[key].price,
                productOfferPrice: cartProducts[key].offerPrice,
            });
    }


};
```

I tried to use the same logic i used in expo app which works fine with expo and giving me the required result.

```
const createOrder = async () => {
    try {
        let orderID;
        const ordrRef = collection(db, "Order")
        await addDoc(ordrRef, {
            total: cartItemTotalAmount,
            userId: userID,
            timestamp: serverTimestamp()
        }).then((doc) => {
            orderID = doc.id
        })

        for (const key in cartItems) {
            await addDoc(collection(ordrRef, orderID, "products"), {
                productTitle: cartItems[key].productTitle,
                productPrice: cartItems[key].productPrice,
                quantity: cartItems[key].quantity
            })
            dispatch(cartActions.clearCart());

        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error", error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't combine `await` and `then()` in a single block of code. Use one or the other, not both.

```
const placeOrder = async () => {
    let doc = await firestore()
        .collection('Orders')
        .add({
            totalPrice: route?.params?.orderPrice,
            userId: loggedUser,
            createdAt: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        });
    const orderId = doc.id;
    for (const key in cartProducts) {
        doc = await firestore()
            .collection('Orders')
            .doc(orderId)
            .collection('Products')
            .add({
                productTitle: cartProducts[key].title,
                productImage: cartProducts[key].image[0],
                productQuantity: cartProducts[key].quantity,
                productPrice: cartProducts[key].price,
                productOfferPrice: cartProducts[key].offerPrice,
            });
        console.log(doc);
    }
};
```

Even if this doesn't fix the problem you're having, this change may prevent other problems - so I recommend applying it now and going forward.

Comment: thanks. i removed it but still i am having the same issue. Any suggestions will be appreciated.